# Не знапускается uvicorn, cкомпилированный с помощью pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, uvicorn

Существует некоторый `uvicorn`-сервер, который я скомпилировал в `exe` при помощи `pyinstaller`. При запуске EXE, в том месте кода, где запускается непосредственно сам сервер с помощью метода `uvicorn.run()`, происходит нижеследующая ошибка:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging\config.py", line 390, in resolve
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uvicorn.logging'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging\config.py", line 542, in configure
  File "logging\config.py", line 654, in configure_formatter
  File "logging\config.py", line 469, in configure_custom
  File "logging\config.py", line 397, in resolve
  File "logging\config.py", line 390, in resolve
ValueError: Cannot resolve 'uvicorn.logging.DefaultFormatter': No module named 'uvicorn.logging'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 82, in <module>
  File "server.py", line 21, in run
  File "uvicorn\main.py", line 343, in run
  File "uvicorn\config.py", line 180, in __init__
  File "uvicorn\config.py", line 223, in configure_logging
  File "logging\config.py", line 808, in dictConfig
  File "logging\config.py", line 545, in configure
ValueError: Unable to configure formatter 'default'
[7932] Failed to execute script server
```

Модуль `uvicorn.logging` присутствует и нормально функционирует; ошибка проявляется только в компилированной EXE-версии приложения. Использование `hidden-imports`, `--path` при запуске PyInstaller, редактирование `.spec`-файла не помогло.